# How to get the full path of a key in a complex list of dictionary

Tags: python

So i have a complex list with dictionaries and lists as values.
This is the one:

```
list = [
  {"folder1": [
    {"file1": 5},
    {"folder3": [{"file2": 7},
                 {"file3": 10}]},
    {"file4": 9}
  ]
 },
 {"folder2": [
    {"folder4": []},
    {"folder5": [
        {"folder6": [{"file5": 17}]},
        {"file6": 6},
        {"file7": 5}
    ]},
    {"file8": 10}
  ]
 }
]
```

I need to extract the path for each file like a directory tree how is stored on a hdd:
Output sample:

```
output:
folder1/file1
folder1/file4
folder1/folder3/file2
folder1/folder3/file3
folder2/file8
folder2/folder4
folder2/folder5/file6
folder2/folder5/file7
folder2/folder5/folder6/file5
```

Please help, i have been struggling and could not find a way.
Thank you

Comment: Show what you have tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with `yield`:

```
def get_paths(d, seen):
  for a, b in d.items():
    if not isinstance(b, list) or not b:
      yield '{}/{}'.format("/".join(seen), a)
    else:
      for c in b:
        for t in get_paths(c, seen+[a]):
           yield t

print('\n'.join([i for b in data for i in get_paths(b, [])]))
```

Output:

```
folder1/file1
folder1/folder3/file2
folder1/folder3/file3
folder1/file4
folder2/folder4
folder2/folder5/folder6/file5
folder2/folder5/file6
folder2/folder5/file7
folder2/file8
```

Comment: Bravo! I was trying to come up with this solution as well but yours works great.

Comment: Any other solutions without yield? Also this one has errors

Comment: yield f'{"/".join(seen)}/{a}'
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @XNone Please try now. `f'{"/".join(seen)}/{a}' ` is know as an `f-string`, and is only available in Python 3.6-3.7

Comment: Is there a way to do this without yield? i have no idea what yield does, i am a beginner in python and i wanna understand what is happening, the logic of the code